# How to install TeamCity build agent on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, continuous-integration, teamcity, centos7

I am new to CentOS. We have TeamCity Server up and running on Window Server 2012.
I need to install only **TeamCity Agent on CentOS machine**. Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following steps to install build agent on centos 7

```
wget http://server-ip:8111/update/buildAgent.zip
sudo unzip buildAgent.zip
sudo chmod +x bin/agent.sh
```

For more detailed article use following link:

https://www.installvirtual.com/install-teamcity-agent/

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is a [TeamCity Agent docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ariya/centos7-teamcity-agent/~/dockerfile/)

Even if you don't want to run in docker you can follow the steps from the dockerfile (and the parent dockerfile) in a VM running centos, or even an actual machine